# Can I compress the file before upload using built-in feature or external library?

Tags: fine-uploader

Compression is a must for my website, since the files can be compressed to 30% and can reach 100s of MB.
Is this supported?

Thanks,
Uri.

Answer (score 0):

You can do anything you want with a `File`, and then submit the resulting `Blob` to Fine Uploader via [the `addFiles` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#addFiles).